# Why is my apache2 failing on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2

I just updated my server from 14.04 to 16.04 LTS, everything was ok except apache2 started to fail due to syntax error of `modsecurity`.

If I disable that rule from:

```
Oct 09 14:46:04  apache2[8487]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 118 of /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules...
```

It will continue to fail to other different rules, I'm not sure why is this happening, before it worked just fine.

Here is a full log:

```
Oct 09 14:46:03  apache2[8487]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Oct 09 14:46:04  apache2[8487]:  *
Oct 09 14:46:04  apache2[8487]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Oct 09 14:46:04  apache2[8487]: Output of config test was:
Oct 09 14:46:04  apache2[8487]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 118 of /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_20_protocol_violations.conf:

Oct 09 14:46:04  apache2[8487]: ModSecurity: Execution phases can only be specified by chain starter rules.
Oct 09 14:46:04  apache2[8487]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Oct 09 14:46:04  apache2[8487]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Oct 09 14:46:04  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 09 14:46:04  systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

Here is also 118 line from that files:

```
SecRule FILES_NAMES|FILES "['\";=]" \
  "msg:'Attempted multipart/form-data bypass', \
  severity:'2', \
  id:'960000', \
  ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9', \
  rev:'1', \
  maturity:'9', \
  accuracy:'7', \
  logdata:'%{matched_var}', \
  phase:2, \
  block, \
  t:none,t:urlDecodeUni, \
  114 tag:'OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_REQ', \
  115 tag:'CAPEC-272', \
  116 setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}', \
  117 setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score}, \

  118 setvar:'tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_REQ-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}'"
```

**EDIT:**

If I disable rule from where that error is coming, it will continue to fail on other rules, `AH00526: Syntax error on line 192 of ...` , and every time it says:

```
ModSecurity: Execution phases can only be specified by chain starter rules.
```

**And every time it is failing when it comes to this line:**

```
  setvar:'tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_HREQ-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}'"
```

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is in line 118 of `/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules...` ?

Comment: I just added that ...

Comment: Possible cause: you are using an option that became invalid with your version of modsecurity. "conf" files do not change during an update. Software versions do.  Oh and do not focus on line 118. That is where something is found that is wrong but the cause can be on a line before that.

Comment: and in case we do not have experts on this:  http://owasp-modsecurity-core-rule-set.owasp.narkive.com/ might be a good place to ask